# Unload a woff file from Wordpress

Tags: plugins, scripts

I'm trying to improve the speed of my website. However i managed to eliminate all the uncessary file except for this that keeps showing up in Pageinsight (it takes 2.5 sec for the load time).

I'm counting that i can get some valuable suggestions to possible solution to resolve to my issue.

I would like to prevent the following file from loading.

This is the file in question:
**https://www.domain.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.woff**

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What is your specific question - how to prevent that file from being called?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! I would like to prevent it from being called. So that i gain in score and performance.

Comment: You can delete it from the SASS files, assets/css/*.scss, and rebuild the CSS from that using the grunt job in the main plugin directory. However it's only 1-2K and served statically so I can't believe this is causing you any problems? And you'll have to come up with something else for displaying star ratings.

Comment: Since it's in a plugin, it's a best practice to never edit the plugin itself (i.e. touch the SASS and/or CSS files). Whenever the plugin is updated, that change will be overwritten; and your star ratings won't display properly. As Rup mentioned this is such a small file it would have a negligible impact on speed. Focusing on other things you can control, such as compressing images, using less JS, or dequeueing plugin CSS files you don't use much of and just copying the relevant styles into your theme, will likely improve your speed much more.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I did do the other practices, this is like the last thing i have in mind. I do agree the size is a bit small, however it takes now around 680ms to load, that's a half of a second ! What i had in mind is possibly some kind of code snipet that will load at first and be used as a filter to block any loading of the so called file. But if there are no other alternatives i think i can go by this solution